# Como evitar que dos datos se dupliquen en un registro tabla sql

Tags: subconsultas

Explico el caso.
Necesito que en una solicitud de un cliente, no se puedan registrar varios registros con informaciones iguales en dos campos. Ejemplo:
Tabla Solicitudes:

[image: Datos Repetidos en los registros 2 y 3]

En esta tabla podemos ver registros de solicitudes de un mismo cliente, pero el registro 2 y el 3 se repiten en los campos: IdTipoCliente, IdTipoContrato. No puedo permitir que esto suceda, la información de estos dos campos no debe coincidir o repetirse en registros existentes o previos a registrar un nuevo registro o solicitud.

Es como preguntar antes de insertar un nuevo registro en la tabla solicitudes:
¿Existen registros en la tabla Solicitudes que tengan el IdTipoCliente Y IdTipoContrato igual que los que se van a registrar?
Si existe que no lo registre y devuelva la cantidad de registros existentes con esta condición, de lo contrario que devuelva 0, y registre, lo cual indicará que no existen registros previos en la tabla con el IdTipoCliente Y IdTipoContrato que se quiere registrar.

Comment: Puedes agregar una restricción `UNIQUE` que abarque las dos columnas. O puedes hacer una clave primaria compuesta con esos dos campos.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Voy a verificar y te comentaré. Ahora me surge otra pregunta, a ver si puedes ayudarme. ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta donde pueda recuperar registros que cumplan con la condición? Gracias de antemano por el apoyo brindado. Saludos

Comment: Hago la pregunta, por lo siguiente: Si yo ejecuto un Stored Procedure con una consulta que me diga: busca registros donde el IdTipoCliente sea igual al Parametro pasado Y el IdTipoContrato sea igual al parametro pasado. Si me devuelve resultados mayor a cero, entonces no ejecuto la inserción, de lo contrario, la ejecuto. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias a tod@s, ya resolví con la simple consulta, donde previamente busco registros que tengan valores iguales en los dos campos segun los parametros, y si me devuelve que exiten, no inserto, de lo contrario, inserto. Proble lo que @Lobos me sugirió y funciona, pero no lo puedo aplicar, porque hay un campo que si se encuentra en un estado, debe permitir el registro, por eso seleccioné mejor la opción de la consulta. Ahora bien. Puedo en un mismo Stored Procedure Ejecutar la consulta y a la vez evaluar si devuelve registros que coincide con la consulta, que no inserte

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

y gracias por su apoyo.
Les comento que ya resolví la inquietud. Lo resolví con una consulta que primero evalúa si no existe una condición, entonces que inserte. A continuación la instrucción:

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Solicitudes WHERE IdCliente=1 AND IdTipoCliente=5 and IdTipoContrato=3)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Solicitudes
  (IdCliente, IdTipoCliente, IdTipoContrato)
  values 
(1, 5, 3)
   END
END
```

Con esto solo me inserta si no existen los datos requeridos.
Un saludo.